# Doctrine 2: Find by entity with composite primary key

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, associations, doctrine-query

I have two entity classes, `Product` and `OrderEntry`, defined like this (some annotations left out for compactness):

```
class Product {

   /**
    * @Id
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * @Column()
    * @Id
    */
   protected $prodNumber;

   /**
    * @Column()
    * @Id
    */
   protected $group;

   // more cols here
}

class OrderEntry {

   // more cols here

   /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
    * @JoinColumns({
    *      @JoinColumn(name="prodNumber", referencedColumnName="prodNumber"),
    *      @JoinColumn(name="group", referencedColumnName="group")
    * })
    */
   protected $Product;
}
```

Now I want to find an OrderEntry by its associated Product with the query builder. The most logical thing for me would be this:

```
class OrderEntryRepository extends EntityRepository  {

    public function findByProduct($product) {
       $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder('o');
       $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('o.Product', '?1')
          ->setParameter(1, $product)
          ->setMaxResults(1);
       return $qb->getQuery()->execute(); 
    }
}
```

However, this throws an exception that says

> A single-valued association path expression to an entity with a
>   composite primary key is not supported. Explicitly name the components
>   of the composite primary key in the query.

How do I name the components explicitly? I know I could do it with a JOIN, but I have no use for the Product in this case and it would just make the query more expensive.

Comment: There is a spelling error in @ManyToOne. It should be "Product" not "Produkt". Is this intentional?

Comment: No, I've corrected it. It's not the source of the error, though.

Comment: Do you have more than one @Id propery in Product class?

Comment: Yes I do (have added them in the text). Have tried to remove them , but that did also not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid joining the products table with the current mapping:

```
public function findByProduct($product) {
   $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder('o');
   $qb
      ->join('o.Product', 'p')
      ->where('p.prodNumber = ?1')
      ->setParameter(1, $product->getProdNumber())
      ->andWhere('p.group = ?2')
      ->setParameter(2, $product->getGroup())
   ;
   return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(); 
}
```

You can add separate properties to OrderEntry, which would use the same columns as the JoinColumns, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @Column(name="prodNumber")
 */
protected $prodNumber;
```

And then you can use them in conditions:

```
... 
->where('o.prodNumber = ?1')
->setParameter(1, $product->getProdNumber()
...
```